# Show full history of screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have a little script (which prints information into the shell) on my VPS which I run with screen. Everytime I reopen the screen session with `screen -r <name>`, I only see few lines. However, I would like to see the full history (or at least a big portion of it), not just few lines. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Imo see answer below about copy/scrollback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you writing to the screen?

Do you start screen and then run the print script or is another process writing to your screen session? (I will assume the first case)

Probably you want the tee command

```
myPrintScript.sh | tee -a myLog.txt &
```

This will print the data from "myPrintScript" and save a file call log.txt. When ever you need to look back at the print info use

```
cat myLog.txt | less
```

You should be able to see all the log data you want

Let me know if understand your question.

As a bounce you might use ts (form moreutils) to get a timestamp

```
myScript | ts | tee -a myLog.txt&
```

Comment: On reflection, i recommend ignoring  the &, if you are not familiar with them. If you want to learn more look up fg, bg, jobs, control z, and &

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to enter *copy/scrollback mode*, which is done by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> (with default key binding) - see [`man screen`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).